# How can i binding the textBox font size to the textbox height?

Tags: silverlight

I want to do binding the font size in the textbox to the textbox height.

I want to have the possibility to change the page size and the font will grow / shrink according to the textbox size change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's doable internally with the textbox, but you could write a converter, bind it for the text size and work the value out in relation to the page size in code.

Comment: i saw this somewhere - i know its possible without convert.

Comment: You will need a converter either way as you can't use the height directly as font size, but if you want to tie it to the height you also have to make a completely fluid layout with grids to make sure the textboxes do get resized.